# Is kumis haram?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

Is [kumis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumis) (fermented mare's milk, called airag in Mongolia) considered haram? The Wikipedia article on kumis doesn't mention any religion-related issues, even though the majority of Kazakhstanis are Muslim. I've heard that Kazakhstani Muslims are not particularly religious, though.

The Wikipedia article [Islamic dietary laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_dietary_laws) implies kumis is halal:

> Halal restaurant in Almaty, Kazakhstan. Yurta (potatoes with meat) and
>   kumis are made of ingredients considered halal.

Comment: @shA.t what advantage is there of having both a "drinking" and an "alcohol" tag?

Comment: AFAIK, Using tags are for better searching and categorizing, your question is mainly about the ahkam of drinking not about alcohol ;).

Answer (score 1):

I can say in Quran we have:

> And the grazing livestock He has created for you; in them is warmth and [numerous] benefits, and from them you eat. [Qur'an/16:5](https://quran.com/16:5)

So, eating livestocks are halal, Then:

> And [He created] the horses, mules and donkeys for you to ride and [as] adornment. And He creates that which you do not know. [Qur'an/16:8](https://quran.com/16:8)

So, Horses, mules and donkeys are different to livestocks in main usage, I can say when those are good for riding so those are not good for eating, but those are still not haraam, Now, I can say those are makruh to eat.

When we tell about eating livestocks it is also about a livestocks's milk.

---

I can add this when eating a livestock become haraam, drinking its milk will be also haraam.
Some sources add that when a person has sexual intercourse with them those animals become haraam.

Note: AFAIK, In fermented milk products both alcohol and lactic acid may be produced:

> Some Islamic scholars do not consider a halal food even if it is made with all halal ingredients but food flavor in which ethyl alcohol was used as a solvent. But other Ulama recommend Halal product made with all Halal ingredients even if food flavors containing ethyl alcohol as a solvent. [<sup>*source</sup>](http://www.ehalal.org/halal-mechanism-and-technical/alcohol-and-fermented-product)

Comment: kumis includes alcohol as it is fermemted as described by OP you didn't even comment on this.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I add a note about that ;).